# How to plot cluster/node number on a Self Organizing Map

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, som, rna-seq

I'm a neophyte of data analysis with R and I'm analyzing RNAseq data using Self Organizing Maps and the Kohonen package to cluster genes based on trends of expression.
I'm quite satisfied with the results of the analysis, since some target genes I'm interested in are ending up in the same cluster (let's call it clusterX) with others that, based on gene onthology, could be interesting interactors.

I used an hexagonal grid so now I would like to check which are the 6 neighbouring clusters/nodes to clusterX in order to see what genes they include.

Is there a way to know what are the neighbouring clusters to a clusterX of interest?

Is it otherwise possible to plot a map showing the numberID of each cluster?[similarly to what was done for the SOM attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eessr.jpg)

Thanks in advance